# Pure sine inverter?

Tags: inverter, sine

I just bought a van and am planning on traveling across country with my pup. I want an affordable pure sine inverter I can easily use. It is cold here and I’m sure it will get colder as I travel. I cannot afford to replace computer equipment. Money is a concern. What do you recommend? Is there one that can charge while I’m driving, and hold a charge while I’m not running my vehicle? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange. Is there a reason you want a "pure sine" inverter, and not simply an inverter?

Comment: Computer equipment doesn't need pure sine wave. Get a unit with about twice the power rating of your equipment. Any decent inverter should handle charging while driving. Recommending specific products is off topic here.

Comment: You don’t need inverter. Mobile phone, laptop, camera runs on DC. Just buy your desired power bank.

Comment: Hiya. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/13143/56469

Comment: If money was no concern I'd say look at Victron as having a good reputation in the boating community. www.victron.com and look for a local dealer. Otherwise, cheap ones (and back up the computer!) from an RV place. But this is really a better question for an "off grid living" forum of some kind.

Comment: inverters do not hold charges